# SGDClassifier vs LogisticRegression with sgd solver in scikit-learn library

Tags: python, machine-learning, scikit-learn

scikit-learn library has following classifiers which look similar:

- Logistic regression classifier has different solvers and one of them 
  is 'sgd'

http://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.linear_model.LogisticRegression.html#sklearn.linear_model.LogisticRegression

- It also has a different classifier 'SGDClassifier' and the loss
  parameter can be mentioned as 'log' for logistic regression.

http://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.linear_model.SGDClassifier.html#sklearn.linear_model.SGDClassifier

Are they essentially same or different? If they are different, how different is the implementation between two? And how do you decide which one to use given the problem of logistic regression?

Comment: The LogisticRegression-module has no SGD-algorithm (‘newton-cg’, ‘lbfgs’, ‘liblinear’, ‘sag’), but the module SGDClassifier can solve LogisticRegression too. That means you got 5 solvers you can use. There are huge differences between those and some rules to choose are given in the docs (e.g. which one of group 1). SGD is typically used for large-scale problems where it's very efficient. Compared to the others, it might be very dependent on chosen hyperparameters (learning-rate, decay, ...). Bad hyperparameters not only result in slow performance, but also bad results (global-min not reached)

Comment: Thank you. I got confused between 'sag' and 'sgd'. Does 'sag' refer to Stochastic Average Gradient? I thought that is similar to sgd unless Stochastic average gradient is much different than Stochastic average gradient descent.

Comment: @sascha "**SAG**" stands for "**S**tochastic **A**verage **G**radient descent". See http://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/linear_model.html#logistic-regression

Answer (score 22):

Logistic Regression in Sklearn doesn't have a 'sgd' solver though. It implements a log regularized logistic regression : it minimizes the log-probability.

SGDClassifier is a generalized linear classifier that will use Stochastic Gradient Descent as a solver. As it is mentionned here http://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/sgd.html : "Even though SGD has been around in the machine learning community for a long time, it has received a considerable amount of attention just recently in the context of large-scale learning." 
It is easy to implement and efficient. For example, this is one of the solvers that is used for Neural Networks.

With SGDClassifier you can use lots of different loss functions (a function to minimize or maximize to find the optimum solution) that allows you to "tune" your model and find the best sgd based linear model for your data. Indeed, some data structures or some problems will need different loss functions.

In your example, the SGD classifier will have the same loss function as the Logistic Regression but a different solver. Depending on your data, you can have different results. You may try to find the best one using cross validation or even try a grid search cross validation to find the best hyper-parameters.

Hope that answers your questions.

Comment: Very nice answer!

Comment: Thanks for making this so clear! I was not relating the "log" in "loss" to logistic regression!

Answer (score 2):

Basically, SGD is like an umbrella capable to facing different linear functions.
SGD is an approximation algorithm like taking single single points and as the number of point increases it converses more to the optimal solution. Therefore, it is mostly used when the dataset is large.
Logistic Regression uses Gradient descent by default so its slower (if compared on large dataset)
To make SGD perform well for any particular linear function, lets say here logistic Regression we tune the parameters called hyperparameter tuning

Answer (score 1):

All linear classifiers(SVM, logistic regression, a.o.) can use the sgd: Stochastic Gradient Descent